# Executing R script from PHP is not working

Tags: php, r

I was trying to execute this simple R script from PHP as follows. I have placed both these files in /var/www/html and changed their permissions to 777.

**R Script**

```
col1 = c(1,2,3,4,5)
col2 = c(2,2,2,2,2);
df = data.frame(col1,col2);
write.csv(df,'/var/www/html/outputfromR.txt',row.names=FALSE)
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    exec("sudo Rscript test.R");
?>
```

However, the file outputfromR.txt is not being created. Is this a permission issue? How do I resolve it?

Comment: First, I have to ask, what are you ultimately trying to accomplish? There are some considerable risks with this concept, not the least of which is using `sudo` from a PHP script calling R. Is this a place where something like [OpenCPU](http://opencpu.org) or [Rserve](https://rforge.net/Rserve/) might be a better solution?

Comment: @r2evans, what I'm trying to do is, a session variable holds the name of a csv file a user has uploaded. I'm trying to convert this csv file to json and write it in the same location /var/www/html/projectfolder. All this r script does is to convert the csv to json. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: No need to use R, try something like [this gist I found](https://gist.github.com/robflaherty/1185299), and have it output straight to the user for direct download instead of trying to (unnecessarily) save it locally first.